# GCM push when android device is offline: Extra is null

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem regarding gcm push when my android device is offline (shut off). When the device is online, the push works perfectly and sends a specific string extra called 'name' to all registered devices.

But if my device is completely shut off during push, after starting the device I get the push but without the string extra 'name'. Here are all extras infos I get from the received push. The 'name' extra is missing:

```
09-12 08:16:13.249: D/SERVICE(2461): PUSH: MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE;
09-12 08:16:13.249: D/SERVICE(2461): Dumping Intent start
09-12 08:16:13.249: D/SERVICE(2461): [from=116398362512]
09-12 08:16:13.249: D/SERVICE(2461): [android.support.content.wakelockid=1]
09-12 08:16:13.249: D/SERVICE(2461): [collapse_key=do_not_collapse]
```

Strangely, when I don't shut my device off and turn only plane-mode on during push, the extra in the delayed push exists. Did I forget something?

I'm using a php script to send the pushs from my server to gcm and the time-to-live value of my push is default (4 weeks). In all cases the gcm server returns successfully send to all registered devices (even if offline).